# VBNet How to know if background worker is already cancelled

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

currently, i have this code: **My_BgWorkerB** is the Name of my BackGround Worker

```
    If My_BgWorkerB.IsBusy Then
        If My_BgWorkerB.WorkerSupportsCancellation Then
            My_BgWorkerB.CancelAsync()
        End If

        ' in this part i want to know if the background worker is already stopped
        ' so that i can start it again

        ' My_BgWorkerB.RunWorkerAsync() ' => this should be triggered if the worker
                                        '    has already been stop.

    Else
        My_BgWorkerB.RunWorkerAsync()
    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is check the `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs` [Cancelled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.asynccompletedeventargs.cancelled.aspx) property in your BGW's `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler.  If it's true restart your BGW using the `RunWorkerAsync()` method.

Something like this:

```
Private Sub My_BgWorkerB_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles My_BgWorkerB.RunWorkerCompleted
    If e.Cancelled Then
       My_BgWorkerB.RunWorkerAsync()  
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: what if i close the form and the worker is still busy? does it throws an error?

Comment: @johntotetwoo No, the BGW will just stop as the form which 'owns' the BGW closes.  This itself won't throw any exceptions.  However, if you need to run code in your BGW's RunWorkerCompleted event handler even if the user closes the form on your running BGW, you can use your form's FormClosing event to call your BGW's CancelAsync() [to be honest I'm not sure if the form will close before the BGW has a chance to cancel, or if you'll need to cancel the form closing in the FormClosing event handler and close from the BGW RunWorkerCompleted handler -- let me know if you need clarification here].